# Qtranslate changes to default language clicking any son post

Tags: redirect, qtranslate

I'm using qtranslate and it works fine except this bug.

I switch to any language different of the default one.

If I click in any post of root category the address given is ok with /?lang=eng
but if I click on a post of lower level, it changes to default language.

Ex

www.domain.es/1category/A_post/?lang=en
* here A_post is a post

www.domain.es/1category/A_post/b_post/
* here A-post is a category but b_post has no reference to language

In this case I assing the name of "a_post" as a post and for the deeper level as category

I have been googling for hours with no solution at all,

Basically when I get deeper into the site, qtranslate doesn't respect the chosen language and changes  to default. It's required switch in every page visited to be able to read the  site in a different language than the default one.

Any suggestion and help is welcome

Thanks by advance

WP 3.5.2
Qtrasnlate 3.5.35
Theme: U-Design 1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [qTranslate Slug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/) plugin which improves some deficiencies of qTranslate plugin.